# Grub error 18, gparted not showing anything

Tags: ubuntu, hard-drive, boot, grub

Some week ago I started having some problems with my pc, sometimes it just freezed not allowing me to do anything. I had to turn it off and on and sometimes do it a couple of time even at startup.

Now it does not start at all, grub is giving me error 18. I have found that a solution is to create a bootable partition in the first sector of the disk.
gparted does not recognize any partition, the window in which there would be my partitions is empty.
`sudo fdisk -l` does not output anything.
If I type `sudo mount /dev/sda` and then tab tab to autocomplete these are the devices coming out: sda sda1 sda2 sda5.
If I launch `sudo mount -t ext3 /dev/sda1 disk` I get the following error:

```
mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sda1,
   missing codepage or helper program, or other error
   In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
   dmesg | tail  or so
```

`dmesg` outputs

```
[ 1831.974847] EXT3-fs: unable to read superblock
```

Do you know how to solve this issue? I'm not completely sure this is a software problem, should I try with a new hard disk?

Comment: I think my hard disk is gone. :(

Comment: did you try booting to a liveCD and running *fsck* on */dev/sda1*?

Comment: @quack quixote: No, I haven't, that's something I discovered just yesterday when I got a similar problem on a usb disk... I'll try today, thank you.